# wordpress get related custom post by tag

Tags: wordpress

I have one custom post type:"videos", and i use the default tag for the videos post.
Now i would like to get all the videos posts that have the same tags.
First thing is to get all the tags, here is my code:

```
 $tags =wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag');
```

i also tried

```
$tags =the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tag');
```

Both of them does not work. They return empty array().

I can see all the posts in dashboard by link:

```
videostags=ihealth&post_type=videos
```

Another question is can i get all the posts by tag id like this:

```
                $args=array(
                  'tag__in' => 4,
                  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                  'showposts'=>5,
                  'ignore_sticky_posts'=>1
                );

               $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all the tag use this function

```
get_tags()
```

for second question yes you can get all the posts by above mentioned code..

use $my_query in loop you will get the post.

Comment: I just found the "tag" and "category" under video type is 'taxonomy', that's why my code does not work. thanks any way.